# Location Permission changed when upgraded the app

Tags: android, permissions, location

Before updating the app **location permission** was given "**Allow all the time**".After updating the app it automatically changed to "**Allow While using the app**".I want to know how it's changing.

Comment: What target SDK of app before upgrade & after. Also on what device/OS version are you testing on. Related: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#access_when_device_is_upgraded_to

Comment: Before target SDK is 28 after updating it is 29. And I am testing in one plus Android 10

Comment: So: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#access_revoked_when_updating_target_api_level_on_devices which states your background access is revoked

Comment: Hi Morrison, even from target SDK 28 to 28 also location permission is going to **Allow awhile using the app**. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: **Allow while using the app** is 'foreground'. From the documentation you will need to check location permissions and re-ask user.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you so much 